# ellipse chord length along its axis.

Tags: conic-sections, elliptic-curves

how to determine the position in an ellipse, where the chord length is equal to its minor axis and perpendicular to the major axis?
Is there any equation for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find $x_0$ such that the $y_0$ satisfying $$\frac{x_0^2}{a^2} + \frac{y_0^2}{b^2} = 1$$ is equal to $a.$ You should be able to solve this.

Comment: I was thinking about complicated equations and got confused. Now, I get it. 
Thank you!